# How to detect current resource route in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a resource route like this :

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController')
```

I want to know current route is one of routes from this resource or not .

Answer (score 4):

Need to import `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;`

**To get current Route info**

Accessing The Current Route- You may use the `current`, `currentRouteName`, and `currentRouteAction` methods on the Route facade to access information about the route handling the incoming request:

```
$route = Route::current();

$name = Route::currentRouteName();

$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

**To get current Controller info**

```
$controller = Route::current()->getController();
```

**Retrieving The Request Path**

The path method returns the request's path information. So, if the incoming request is targeted at http://example.com/foo/bar, the path method will return `foo/bar`:

```
$uri = $request->path();
```

The `is` method allows you to verify that the incoming request path matches a given pattern. You may use the * character as a wildcard when utilizing this method:

```
if ($request->is('admin/*')) {
    //
}
```

**Retrieving The Request URL**

To retrieve the full URL for the incoming request you may use the `url` or `fullUrl` methods. The `url` method will return the URL without the query string, while the `fullUrl` method includes the query string:

```
// Without Query String...
$url = $request->url();

// With Query String...
$url = $request->fullUrl();
```

Comment: No, I know these . but I want know by one code like this : request()->routeIs('posts.index').

Comment: So,you want to check current route is from that resource `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController')` or not?

Comment: Yes I want do it